# "Something wrong here, didn't expect PACKAGE to be resumed" error in android Logcat

Tags: android, crash, orientation, nullpointerexception, logcat

I have an Android app modeled after the `LunarLander` example by Google. I am debugging it on a real device, (`Motorola Droid`) with `Android 2.0`. When the orientation changes, the program crashes on a `NullPointerException`. Logcat from just before crash:

```
02-01 00:24:27.956: DEBUG/nate(8358): Starting Game
02-01 00:24:36.878: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1086): GC freed 1788 objects / 92256 bytes in 1389ms
02-01 00:24:38.542: INFO/WindowManager(1021): Setting rotation to 1, animFlags=0
02-01 00:24:38.558: INFO/ActivityManager(1021): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/4 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=2/2 orien=2 layout=34}
02-01 00:24:38.620: WARN/UsageStats(1021): Something wrong here, didnt expect org.nifong.leeder to be resumed
02-01 00:24:38.886: DEBUG/nate(8358): New Surface dimensions: 854x442
02-01 00:24:38.886: DEBUG/nate(8358): flies was null
```

The first line that worries me is `"Something wrong here"` at `24:38.620`. I have no idea what it means, but I think its due to me not reacting properly to the screen change.

Next I get a debug message that I printed myself from within my own method `surfaceChanged()` about the new surface dimensions.

Then I print out debug message about whether flies was `null`. `flies` is the field that eventually causes the `NullPointerException`. Its created once, and never written to again for the rest of the program. I know that it was not null before the crash, because it was read several times.

Does anyone have a clue how my private member variable came to be null just by these clues?

I would include code but there is a lot of it and I don't know what would be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by adding these two lines to the activity tag in my manifest file

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

this says that my application will handle keyboard and orientation changes on its own (by doing nothing) and prefers to run in landscape all the time.

Comment: This maybe a solution for your app, depending on your use case. In my view this is a rude behaviour forcing the user in a usage behaviour he maybe dislikes...

Answer (score 3):

Orientation changes in Android affect state. Basically, your activity is destroyed and recreated. You must therefore be aware of what [Android lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lcycles) events will be called and how to save state.

You also need to be wary of `static` instances and how that affects this lifecycle.

[Here is a blog post](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40792/0/page/4) explaining some of this.